# SVG: partial path drawing

Tags: svg, path

I need to draw a dashed path. I set initial and final point, but I need to draw only a part of this curve. For example from start to a predefined percentage. Is it possible?

best regards

Comment: What have you tried so far? On Stack Overflow you are expected to put a good amount of effort in before asking. The more detail you can provide the better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dash pattern to draw part of a line.

```html
<svg>
  <path d="M 0,50 L 300,50" stroke="#ddd" stroke-width="20"/>
  <path d="M 0,50 L 300,50" stroke="#d33" stroke-width="20"
        stroke-dasharray="200 100"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to alter the final point so that it is the desired percentage you wish to draw and then just draw the full line